# Why Android versions on Maven Central don't include Google Apis (maps)?

Tags: android, google-maps, maven, sdk

[Most of the jars of Android SDKs are now in maven central](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5253029/693752), but none of the Google Api versions of SDKs. Do you know why ? Is there any restriction to add them ?

Update : I am not looking for a workaround ([like adding them locally to my repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10385664/693752)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is prohibited by [Android SDK EULA](http://developer.android.com/sdk/terms.html):

> 1.1 The Android Software Development Kit **(referred to in this License Agreement as the "SDK" and specifically including the Android system files, packaged APIs, and Google APIs add-ons)** is licensed to you subject to the terms of this License Agreement. This License Agreement forms a legally binding contract between you and Google in relation to your use of the SDK.
>
> ... ...
>
> 3.3 You may not use the SDK for any purpose not expressly permitted by this License Agreement.  Except to the extent required by applicable third party licenses, **you may not: (a) copy (except for backup purposes), modify, adapt, redistribute, decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, or create derivative works of the SDK or any part of the SDK;** or (b) load any part of the SDK onto a mobile handset or any other hardware device except a personal computer, combine any part of the SDK with other software, or distribute any software or device incorporating a part of the SDK.

The approach [Android for Maven](http://android4maven.sourceforge.net/) used is compile android.jar from source and pulls out source and resource files to replicate android.jar in the SDK. As you can see, this is obviously not possible for some Google APIs addon which is close source, like Maps.

The good news is Android team starts reinventing the build system (more details at [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system)), hopefully the close source jars will be taken care and managed in central repository by Android team, see Manfred's reply [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/maven-android-developers/lQCMRKInuyk).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and for pointing the actual google discussion group thread. It looks very promising and most problems related to industrialization of Android will be adressed.

Comment: Has this situation changed in the last year?