# Why there is no Android SDK 4.4 in the Maven Repository?

Tags: android, maven, repository

I know that the android sdk .jars in the maven repository are user uploads and not provided by google, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253029/why-arent-the-android-sdk-jars-in-any-maven-repository). What I want to know is why the upload stopped at version 4.1.1.4, when you [look here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/android). Android is at verison 4.4 the uploads are at 4.1.X.X.

- Is the converting that complicated?
- Are they no longer allowed to do so?
- Or do they just stopped for an other reason? (No time, ect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been doing this as part of the [Android4Maven](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android4maven/) project and just have not had the time to do the build and deployment. We welcome any help...

As an alternative please use my [Android Maven SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer).

Comment: Does it mean that android 4.4 based apps won't be able to compile with Maven ?

Comment: No... it just means for now you have to use the Android Maven SDK Deployer to get the android 4.4. jars into your local repository or better your repository manager and therefore provide them to Maven.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles upon this and is wondering what the options are, you can simply stick to the Android SDK installer without needing the Maven Android SDK Deployer.

All developers on your project will still need to install the Android SDK and set their ANDROID_HOME path.

Install the Android SDK Extras repositories that you need, like "Android Support Repository".

If you want to include, say, "appcompat-v7", here's a Scala `build.sbt` example (something similar would work in Gradle):

```
val android_home = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")

val android_support = s"file:///$android_home/extras/android/m2repository"

resolvers += "Android Support Repository" at android_support 

libraryDependencies += "com.android.support" % "appcompat-v7" % "19.+"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the Android developers do not publish the android jars to Maven any more, you can easily install them in your local repository and then use them normally:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-19/android.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=android -Dversion=4.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

will be successfully resolved both by Eclipse IDE + m2e-android and by `android-maven-plugin` when running Maven.