# Unzip downloaded file in gradle downloaded from own nexus server

Tags: android, gradle

I have downloaded a file from our nexus server by following this post: [gradle - download and unzip file from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023069/gradle-download-and-unzip-file-from-url) in my android project, first specifying the target:

```
compile 'net.myapp.gwt:MyAppGWT:1.0:android@zip'
```

and then I have this unzip task:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {

    def zipPath = project.configurations.compile.find {it.name.startsWith("net.myapp.gwt")}
    println zipPath
    def zipFile = file(zipPath)
    def outputDir = file('src/main/assets/')

    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
}
```

The problem is that the line

```
project.configurations.compile
```

generates the weirdest error. Applying it gives me following error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Applications/AndroioStudio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
file:/Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
https://nexus.domain.net/content/repositories/apps-releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
https://nexus.domain.net/content/repositories/apps-releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
Required by:
apps-android:app:unspecified

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Now, all of a sudden it can't find

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
```

which isn't a problem if I remove that line.

Comment: Interesting. I will try it out as soon as I get right permissions to our nexus server!

Comment: It did work. I would like to tribute you to the right answer, so if you like you can post your comment as an answer and I give you credit for it (rather than me posting the answer to my own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appcompat` comes from your local sdk folder. But when you try to access `configs.compile`, gradle is trying to resolve all dependencies including appcompat from the external repos, and fails when it (unsurprisingly) doesn't find appcompat.

I'm not sure what the "right" solution is, but a possible workaround is to publish android sdk dependencies to your local maven or nexus repo. Here's one way to do that: github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Some answers [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045712/gradle-build-android-project-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-error-but-i-t) might help too.

Lastly, it might be possible to treat your SDK folder as a local maven repo. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253029/why-arent-the-android-sdk-jars-in-any-maven-repository/27939407#27939407).

Answer (score 1):

@RaGe was right. Adding the libraries to our local repo server did the trick. Even though, as you state, this is a workaround and perhaps in the long run would be nice to find a better solution.